# Facebook Graph API subscribing to user threads

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to receive realtime updates of user threads via graph api(2.x), and I work around with Graph API Explore posting a request like below to make a subscription;

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/MY_FB_ID/subscriptions

# with these params

 access_token: MY_VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
 object: user
 fields: threads
 verify_token: foo-bar
 callback_url: http://example.com/callbacks
```

then I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Application cannot subscribe to notifications", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

And when I change `threads` with `name`, for example, it returns this response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2201) response does not match challenge, expected value = '1872122487', received='<!doctype html>\n<htm...'", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2201
  }
}
```

I think this error is good because Facebook API accepts a request and try to verify the server to send notifications exists and setup correctly, but the first one is not good apparently.

So what's odd is both `threads` and `name` are listed as valid fields for `user` object on the document, but only `threads` is not accepted.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0#subscribefields

Any idea about what is wrong with this. I should not do this on explore? Or it's not even possible to subscribe user threads via graph api?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/thread: _“This endpoint is only accessible for users that are developers of the app making the request.”_

Comment: CBroe, thanks for the comment, but I can get Thread object with Graph API Explore. My problem is that I can't create a subscription to receive realtime updates of threads. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found we cannot receive realtime updates of user/threads unless being whitelisted by facebook, at least for now.